# js serialize correct format

Tags: javascript, php

I have html form and need serialize this for pass to ajax.
When i use js serialize:

`var sFormSpecValues = $('form#frmFilter').serialize();`

And in input is for example, space or '|' symbol it will be replace to wrong symbols. 
For example, value '**test comment| 22.04**' will replaced  to : '**test+comment%7C+22.04**'

Then i need save these data in php, but above value is wrong, i need 'test comment' text in my string. 
How can i fix it in js or in php? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about that, it is url-encoding

Comment: Looks like you need to understand url encoding. Did you look at `$_GET` in the PHP Code

Comment: https://www.urlencoder.io/learn/

Comment: is it correct in php use function urldecode for solve problem?

Comment: Go crazy and try it? :-)

Comment: I tried it)) But i want be sure  that it is correct solution and it is not my bike solution =)

Comment: If you want to decode a url encoded string, then yes, `urldecode()` is the correct tool.